# Stream from local textfile in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am trying to stream from local text file.

```
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("spark://antonis-dell:7077").setAppName("Kafka_Spark")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)  # .getOrCreate()
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)


lines = ssc.textFileStream("file:///home/antonis/repos/GLASSEAS/Anomaly_Detector/dataset/")
lines.pprint()
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Nothing seems to work from previous responses on stackoverflow.

I have tried an empty `dataset` folder and then to pass the txt file, I have tried with `file:/`, but nothing works.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to complete your code sample with ssc.start and ssc.awaitTermination calls.

```
...
lines = ssc.textFileStream("/home/antonis/repos/GLASSEAS/Anomaly_Detector/dataset/")
  .pprint()
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

This [spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#a-quick-example) is great for getting started (in their example they use socketTextStream, but everything else applies to your case)

Comment: I have already added. Sorry It was not in the question. It does not work

Comment: Do you see empty microbatches? Like: Time: 1590564465000 ms. Or nothing at all?

Comment: Empty microbatches

Comment: Do you have a real multinode cluster? That "/home/antonis/..." directory should exist on Spark worker nodes. Also I think you need to start adding files to that folder after you start your streaming app

Comment: I have a multinode cluster in my machine. Yes I have add files after start streaming. I manage to do this with a script and now I have an error saying WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources. Maybe, I have to add more memory on the worker nodes

Comment: You might have done this already, but check Spark's web UI http://antonis-dell:8080. Workers should be listed there (with their memory and cores). Then check the executors tab of the running application. It has to have executors. If everything looks good, try relaunching your workers with more resources

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with spark session  instead of spark context like this

```
sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate()
lines = sparkSession.readStream.textFile("file:///home/antonis/repos/GLASSEAS/Anomaly_Detector/dataset/")
```